# Вставка текста в определенное место

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Как сделать вставку текста между определенным текстом
У меня получилось сделать через `<span>`, но проблема в том, что на кликабельной ссылке виден `<span>`.

```js
var P = document.querySelector('#wall');
  P.onclick = function() {
    if (P.checked) {
      document.getElementById('wall1').innerHTML =  'wall,' ;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('wall1').innerHTML =  '' ;      
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="wall">Отправка постов<br>
            
<a href='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4616152&scope=<span id="wall1"></span>&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token'><b>ссылке</b></a>
```

Comment: Нужно вставить текст вместо `<span id="wall1"></span>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не рабочий код. Сделайте с помощью `replace`:

```js
var P = document.querySelector('#wall'),
    a = document.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
P.onclick = function() {
  if (P.checked) {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=(?:[A-Za-z_0-9-]+\,?)*)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1wall,$2'));
  } else {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1$2'));
  }
  console.log(a.getAttribute('href')); // Это что бы показать содержимое href
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="wall">Отправка постов<br>
            
<a href='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4616152&scope=&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token'><b>ссылке</b></a>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, а можно сделать поиск не до &, чтобы replace искал только scope, и после его вставлял, чтобы он делал поиск не между scope и &. Чтобы добавить второй метод, например audio

Comment: @nicolaa, в каком смысле?

Comment: Как добавить второй метод, например audio, replace делает поиск между &scope= и &, когда я добавляю второй метод, он заменяет первый

Comment: @nicolaa, я подправил ответ. Смотрите